# F# passing in a C# method into another C# method expecting Func<> parameter

Tags: f#

In a c# dll I have a method, that takes func parameters:

```
public static AttrDiffRule Create<T>(string a_attr, string b_attr, Func<IAttrProxy,IAttrProxy,T,bool> parametricRule, T ruleParam, string desc = null)
```

and some predefined default methods intended for it:

```
public static bool NumberEqualsWithTolerance(IAttrProxy a, IAttrProxy b, double tolerance)
```

Now when using this in C#, I can write the following and it works:

```
var tmp = DefaultRules.Create("fds", "fds", DefaultRules.NumberEqualsWithTolerance, 10.0);
```

But, in F# this:

```
let attrRule = DefaultRules.Create("fd","fdsa", DefaultRules.NumberEqualsWithTolerance, 89.)
```

gives syntax error: "Error  FS0002  This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected"

What would be the correct way to pass a C# static method into a parameter expecting a Func<> in F#?

It is important to actually pass in the function, and not a lambda wrapper, because the Create method's job is to use the argument function's MethodInfo, which gets hidden by the lambda wrapper's one.

The passed in function does not have overloads, also tried with specifying the type in place like

```
(DefaultRules.NumberEqualsWithTolerance : Func<IAttrProxy,IAttrProxy,float,bool>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of F# being very thoughtful on your behalf - by helping you write more idiomatic F#.

In .NET, you are not actually passing in the function, as if it's a member reference, rather you are passing in a delegate object of type `Func<>`. The construction of the delegate object is done implicitly by C# when it has the necessary type information.

We can see this more clearly if we refactor this into an actual delegate type:

```
public delegate bool ParametricRule<T>(IAttrProxy a, IAttrProxy b, T value);

public static AttrDiffRule Create<T>(string a_attr, string b_attr, ParametricRule<T> parametricRule, T ruleParam, string desc = null)
{
    return default;
}
```

If you try to construct a `ParametricRule` in F#, you'll see that its type is:

```
ParametricRule(IAttrProxy -> IAttrProxy -> 'a -> bool)
```

The rationale is that this way you can use regular F# functions, instead of some un-F#ish tupled input function. And this why it doesn't work in your case.
Because you're trying to throw the tupled version from C# right back at it.

So if you refactor your C# implementation to:

```
protected static bool NumberEqualsWithToleranceImpl(IAttrProxy a, IAttrProxy b, float tolerance)
{
    return default;
}

public static ParametricRule<float> NumberEqualsWithTolerance => NumberEqualsWithToleranceImpl;
```

you'll see that it works like you'd expect it to, both from F# and C#.

```
let attrRule = DefaultRules.Create("fd","fdsa", DefaultRules.NumberEqualsWithTolerance, 89.0f) //compiles, yay!
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the type resolution has trouble when passing a method as a function parameter, because there can be overloads on the method that make the signature ambiguous.  You can just wrap the function in a lambda that passes the parameters.

```ml
let attrRule = 
    DefaultRules.Create(
        "fd",
        "fdsa", 
        (fun a b tolerance -> DefaultRules.NumberEqualsWithTolerance(a, b, tolerance)), 
        89.0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem, due to a constraint not part of the original question: The .Create method's main job is to use the passed in function's MethodInfo, which is overridden by the lambda wrapping.

Comment: @Balinth If the intent is to use the `MethodInfo`, then you should just pass the `MethodInfo`.  Your function shouldn't rely on the caller knowing the implementation details; any function that meets the signature should work.  Therefore, if what you really need is a `MethodInfo` object, you should have a `MethodInfo` object in your formal parameters.

Comment: I mean, the whole point of the method is that you don't have to pass in additional description for the most often used cases, there is already an overload that takes directly a string, where you can specify what the method would take from the MethodInfo, when you pass in a more specific lambda rule. Obviously one additional parameter wont make or break the tool, but this is not about knowing the implementation, this is about being able to pass in the parameters which should be able to be passed in.